# Resize (more) am i parsing floats correctl? (using sscanf)

Tags: c, cs50

I recently finished resize less and decided to move on to more. The first thing it asks me to do is to be able 2 parse floats using `atof` and `sscanf`. After a bit of research i came up with using either to get a floating point number, however if I try and resize by 2.5 for instance I get this error:

```
*** Error in `./resize': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000002100480 ***
```

Aborted, here's the code i wrote to parse a floating point number from the user via command line just want to know if its correct before i try and move on.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: copy infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames    
    float n = 0;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &n);
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    // prints valve of f for debugging
    printf("f = %f.\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sscanf return the number of items that it successfully converts. You should consider checking that to make sure it worked. For instance if  the user entered a text instead of a number for that command line argument.

Comment: the function: `atof()` is not a good choice as it does not tell you if an error occurred.  Suggest using: `strtof()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using sscanf correctly. If you're confused with `sscanf`, you should checkout the `strtof()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: copy infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    float n = 0;
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    // prints valve of f for debugging
    n = strtof(argv[1], NULL);
    printf("%f\n", n);
}
```

You should still learn how to use sscanf (`man` is your friend) for more complicated parsing operations. But for single type parsing, always use the `strtoxxx()` family of functions.

Comment: *You should still learn how to use sscanf (`man` is your friend) for more complicated parsing operations.*  The entire `scanf()` family of functions is absolutely horrible for complicated parsing.  For example, you can't in general use the same format string to `sprintf()` a record and then `sscanf()` the string generated.  The `f` in `scanf` is for "formatted", where the parsing needed is actually very limited.

Comment: It's just a lot more convenient to use sscanf when parsing multiple variables in one line. Otherwise, I'd have to do multiple calls to the `strtoxxx()` family of functions. I wasn't talking about parsing a language with `sscanf()`.